# How would I get my python program to play audio?

Tags: python, streamlit

I want my python project to play an `.mp3` file from my computer if it does not detect eyes and then stop playing the `.mp3` file when eyes are detected. I am displaying the opencv window on a Streamlit web app.

```
def data_page():
    st.header("Focus Page")
    class VideoTransformer(streamlit_webrtc.VideoTransformerBase):
        def __init__(self):
            self.eye_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier(cv2.data.haarcascades + 'haarcascade_eye.xml')

        def transform(self, frame):
            img = frame.to_ndarray(format="bgr24")

            gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
            eyes = self.eye_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray, scaleFactor=1.3, minNeighbors=5)

            if len(eyes) == 0:
                cv2.putText(img, "No eyes detected", (50, 50), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 1, (0, 255, 255), 2, cv2.LINE_4)
            else:
                for (x, y, w, h) in eyes:
                    cv2.rectangle(img, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (0, 255, 0), 2)

            return img

    webrtc_ctx = streamlit_webrtc.webrtc_streamer(key="example", mode=streamlit_webrtc.WebRtcMode.SENDRECV,
                                                  video_transformer_factory=VideoTransformer)
```

I tried using `st.audio` however the audio would not play if the eyes were not detected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best method is using **PyGame** library.
It should be like this:

```
from pygame import mixer
mixer.init()
mixer.music.load("youraudio.mp3")
mixer.music.play()
```

Google about it for complete guide. Mix this method with your own code.

Answer (score 0):

You could use pygame. If you don't want to install any librarys or stuff like that and you are on windows, you can use winsound. https://docs.python.org/3/library/winsound.html

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).